# Render Html + Javascript in a .Net headless browser

Tags: javascript, html, .net, webbrowser-control, render

There is a need to render Html page with simple Javascript using a headless browser in .Net c# (server side) application. Finally I need to get rendered Html source code.

I think I can use some .free/opensource libraries for rendering such as:

[Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/)

[GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/)

[CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

[Berkelium](https://github.com/berkelium/berkelium)

Requirement example:

**Html code before render:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function FormatCurrency(value) {
            document.write(value.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'decimal', minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td><script>FormatCurrency(275)</script></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Html code after render:** (Expected result)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function FormatCurrency(value) {
            document.write(value.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'decimal', minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>275.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The difference is the javascript code `<td><script>FormatCurrency(275)</script></td>` is rendered as `<td>275.00</td>`.

Could anyone help me to achieve my requirement by adding some sample code?
Feel free to use any free .net browser control library in sample code.

Note:
I can pass either html code or url to the rendering method.
As I need to implement this this in server side, I think I should strict to headless browser.